# How to add multiple lines in html text forms?

Tags: html

I've been having a bit of trouble with a problem that seems as though it should be obvious, but my internet searches yield no results. Essentially, I'm trying to create an image-board like HTML skeleton for a project. However, my text entry box (resized to allow for entrance of more than a few words, doesn't allow for entry of more than one line (hitting enter does not start a new line, and arrow keys don't work either.)Keep in mind that I cannot use javascript or any server side languages. What should I do with this?

The id of the textbox is #postbigger - I heard there was a rows style, but upon trying it got no results. Is there some form of css descriptor I can add? ( This is not a duplicate, as I needed to actually apply the code and remove the resizable effect on )

```css
#postbigger {
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<form>
Post:<br><input id="postbigger" type="text"/><br>
Id Code:<br><input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can't you use a textarea as @zer00ne has mentioned below?

Comment: @PavKR how would I use that in a form? Would I replace input somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`<textarea>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_textarea.asp)

```html
<textarea rows='6' cols='40'></textarea>
```